# Why [1:2] != Array[1:2]

Tags: arrays, syntax, julia

I am learning Julia following the [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia), but I don't understand why the following two commands give different results:

```
julia> [1:2]
1-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:2

julia> Array[1:2]
1-element Array{Array,1}:
 [1,2]
```

Apologies if there is an explanation I haven't seen in the Wikibook, I have looked briefly but didn't find one.

Comment: @user2864740 `Array[[1:2]]` gives yet another result (an array, which contains an array, which contains a range), but that makes sense to me. Maybe what I didn't understand is why `[ a:b ]` is special?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type[a] runs convert on the elements, and there is a simple conversion between a Range to an Array (collect). So `Array[1:2]` converts `1:2` to an array, and then makes an array of objects like that. This is the same thing as why Float64[1;2;3] is an array of Float64.

---

#### These previous parts answer answered the wrong thing. Oops...

`a:b` is not an array, it's a `UnitRange`. Why would you create an array for `A = a:b`? It only takes two numbers to store it, and you can calculate `A[i]` basically for free for any `i`. Using an array would take an amount of memory which is proportional to the `b-a`, and thus for larger arrays would take a lot of time to allocate, whereas allocation for `UnitRange` is essentially free.

These kinds of types in Julia are known as lazy iterators. LinSpace is another. Another interesting set of types are the special matrix types: why use more than an array to store a `Diagonal`? The `UniformScaling` operator acts as the identity matrix while only storing one value (it's scale) to make `A-kI` efficient.

Since Julia has a robust type system, there is no reason to make all of these things arrays. Instead, you can make them a specialized type which will act (`*`, `+`, etc.) and index like an array, but actually aren't. This will make them take less memory and be faster. If you ever need the array, just call `collect(A)` or `full(A)`.

---

I realized that you posted something a little more specific. The reason here is that `Array[1:2]` calls the `getindex` function for an array. This `getindex` function has a special dispatch on a `Range` so that way it "acts like it's indexed by an array" (see the discussion from earlier). So that's "special-cased", but in actuality it just has dispatches to act like an array just like it does with every other function. `[A]` gives an array of `typeof(A)` no matter what A is, so there's no magic here.

---

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear; I understand perfectly that/why `1:2` is an object and not an array. What I don't understand is why `Array[1:2]` seems to expand its argument.

Comment: So from your edit, the difference between the two results is due to an overload of `getindex` specifically for lazy iterators. Any language has its peculiarities, but this one is difficult to understand; it leads to the question of why `A[1:2] == A[[1:2...]]` doesn't it?

Comment: Oh I think I still read your question wrong and answered something else there lol. `Type[a]` runs `convert` on the elements, and there is a simple conversion between a `Range` to an `Array` (`collect`). This is the same thing as why `Float64[1;2;3]` is an array of `Float64`: element-wise conversion.

Comment: That last comment was the missing piece I think, thank you for the explanation :) Would you be able to maybe reshuffle your answer to put the last part first, and I can validate it as the answer!

Comment: I re-arranged the answer as requested.